# PersonAPI Google+ "PERMISSION_DENIED" Error

Tags: android, google-plus

I am trying to fetch Gender and Date of Birth using PersonAPI provided by Google+ but I am receiving a Server Side Error in my Logs.

Here is my Logcat:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
"code" : 403,
"errors" : [ {
"domain" : "global",
"message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
"reason" : "forbidden"
} ],
"message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
"status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

I am using the following Code:

```
ListConnectionsResponse response = peopleService.people().connections()
                .list("people/me")
                .execute();
```

Please tell me what am I missing ? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31587096/1979882

Comment: But I am not retrieving any Access Token manually. All I am doing is getting a PeopleService Object and initiating "people/me" rest call on it.

Comment: I am following this sample https://github.com/Suleiman19/People-API-App

Comment: ok . have you implementer this code? https://github.com/Suleiman19/People-API-App/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/grafixartist/peoples/MainActivity.java#L86

Comment: and this : https://github.com/Suleiman19/People-API-App/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/grafixartist/peoples/MainActivity.java#L122 ?

Comment: I think i have not implemented this (https://github.com/Suleiman19/People-API-App/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/grafixartist/peoples/MainActivity.java#L86) link correctly. I have made the required changes. I am debugging again. Fingers crossed !

Comment: I think this has solved the problem, You may post the Answer. I will happily accept it. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126526/discussion-between-salman-khakwani-and-vyacheslav).

Comment: answered your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hav to authorize before sending any request of Google API.
That is,

```
 GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                // The serverClientId is an OAuth 2.0 web client ID
                .requestServerAuthCode(getString(R.string.clientID))
                .requestEmail()
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN),
                        new Scope(PeopleScopes.CONTACTS_READONLY),
                        new Scope(PeopleScopes.USER_EMAILS_READ),
                        new Scope(PeopleScopes.USERINFO_EMAIL),
                        new Scope(PeopleScopes.USER_PHONENUMBERS_READ))
                .build();


        // To connect with Google Play Services and Sign In
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, signInOptions)
                .build();
```

And catch success callback:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case RC_INTENT:
                Log.d(TAG, "sign in result");
                GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);

                if (result.isSuccess()) {
                    GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult:GET_TOKEN:success:" + result.getStatus().isSuccess());
                    // This is what we need to exchange with the server.
                    Log.d(TAG, "auth Code:" + acct.getServerAuthCode());

                   // PUT YOUR WANTED CODE HERE


                } else {

                    Log.d(TAG, result.getStatus().toString() + "\nmsg: " + result.getStatus().getStatusMessage());
                }
                break;

        }
    }
```